# Header background-image doesn't cover all header content

Tags: html, css

In a website I'm creating for a friend, I'm creating a header (a div labeled as such) with two images (also wrapped in divs) and a company name and slogan (more divs).

The primary purpose of the header div is to wrap all header content for easy positioning and to enable a background image for the header.

The problem is that the background image of the header refuses to fill the whole background of the actual header content. It only fills out whatever I specify as padding on the header div.

In my head, it seems that a container div should have the same size as the sum of its subdivs' sizes. Therefore, specifying a background image for a parent div should theoretically provide a background which fills the background area of all the child divs as well. However, in practice, this is appearing to not be the case.

Can anyone enlighten me what I'm missing? How can I get an image to act as a background for the entire header? I've posted the relevant (generic) code here: http://codepen.io/deadwanderer/pen/LnGKC/

As you can see, the header div's borders essentially act as a line at the top of the content, when they should be a box that surrounds it.

Thanks for any help and/or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the divs since you have floating divs:

clear:both;

try this:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="leftpic">
     <img src="" alt="Left Image" class="pic"/>
  </div>
  <div class="rightpic">
    <img src="" alt="Right Image" class="pic"/>
  </div>
  <div class="hdrtext">
    <div class="companyName">Company Name</div>
    <div class="companySlogan">Company Slogan</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div> <!-- Notice this added line -->
</div>
```

SEE DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cKByp

Read about Clearfixs here: http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed; thanks! Ps, first line of that article: "You've heard of 'clearing floats', but do you really understand it?" My answer: Obviously not!